# Estimating demand from partially right-censored sales data

Tags: predictive-models, econometrics, censoring, business-intelligence

Imagine a company is having limited-time sales events of certain limited editions of their products. Let's consider 3 such events, each featuring a different product, with limited inventory of 600 units and a limited time window of 12 hours. For these sales a time series is gathered, containing the current inventory over time.

- Product A: all 600 units are sold in 1 hour
- Product B: all 600 units are sold within 6 hours
- Product C: 430 units are sold within the timeframe, 170 units are left over

The sales department wants you to suggest how the demand, as in how many units could potentially be sold, could be estimated for similar articles. The question to start with however is: **what was the demand for A, B, and C?**

We know that 430 units of C were sold and not more, at least in this time frame that's as much as was in demand apparently. **But what about A and B**? We know it was at least 600, but there is a limit to it.
My assumption is that the rate at which the units sell changes over time, reducing as demand is getting satisfied more and more.

I'm interested if there's a way of using the change in inventory over time to provide a prediction interval of how many units are likely still sellable. For example, product A is unlikely to continue selling at 600 units per hour for long, but it's feasible to assume that it would sell 700 in total.

What kind of models should I look into for this?